# Does Max-SNP hard imply NP-hard

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

I have difficulties understanding the definition of the class [Max-SNP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNP_%28complexity%29) (optimization variant of **strict NP**), thus I have to following basic question:

```
If a problem is known to be Max-SNP hard, does this imply NP-hardness of the problem?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\maxsnp}{\mathsf{Max}\text{-}\mathsf{SNP}}$The definition of $\maxsnp$ gives us the ability to define:

1. Universal ($\forall$) and existential ($\exists$) quantifiers over variables
2. Existential quantifiers over relations

With this definition we can define $\mathsf{Max}$-$\mathsf{SAT}$:

$$\exists x, \forall y \text{ such that } |\psi(y)| \leq |\psi(x)|$$ where $|\psi(x)|$ is the number of clauses satisfied in formula $\psi$ under assignment $x$.

Given that $\mathsf{Max}$-$\mathsf{SAT}$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-$\mathsf{Hard}$, we see that $\mathsf{NP}$-$\mathsf{Hardness}$ is implied from $\maxsnp$.